# mongoose.Types.ObjectId returns same value at same timestamp or not?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using **nonce** for handling **concurrent edits** in mongodb, I am using mongoose with node.js, Now can anyone please tell me at same timestamp does "**mongoose.Types.ObjectId**" returns same value or different.

Comment: What is your own initial assessment?

Comment: i am printing two logs one after the other but i am getting different value for both.

Comment: may be that is because there is some time delay between two logs that's why i am asking here ??

Comment: ObjectId's are ["likely unique"](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/bson-types/#objectid).

Comment: on the same timestamp also ??